# how to implement Custom lookup function VBA Excel correctly?

Tags: excel, vba

i've been sweating on this for a day now with no success. You'll see from the code.. i have denominated a range, and said.. for each Cell in this Range, from this ActiveCell get the Name which is Cell "A(RowNumber)"
Also
Go to workSheet which is determined by the column heading, and search a range in that page of column B.

If the result lies in column B, then simply write "Yes" in my Table, on that ActiveCell.

I've caught glimpses of it writing the "Yes", but then scrubbing it back out on the next iteration of the loop. NameToSearch stays the same name! i can't understand why! :-(

See Code:

```
Public Function StaffCrossRef()

Dim fso As Object
Dim log As Object
Dim StaffSht As Worksheet
Dim ColNameToSearch As String
Dim ActualNameToSearch As String
Dim StaffPageRange As Range
Dim StaffSearchRange As Range
Dim RangeToSearch As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Builder As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim X As Integer
Dim ThisCell As Range

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set log = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Test\Test.txt")

Set StaffSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff")

WhatRow = ActiveCell.Row
WhatCol = ActiveCell.Column

StaffFirstRow = StaffSht.Cells(2, 1).Row
StaffLastRow = StaffSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set StaffPageRange = StaffSht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(StaffFirstRow, StaffLastRow)
StaffSearchFirst = StaffSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
StaffSearchLast = StaffSht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 2
Set StaffSearchRange = StaffSht.Cells(2, 3).Resize(StaffSearchFirst, StaffSearchLast)

StaffSht.Activate

For Each Cell In StaffSearchRange.Cells

    Cell.Activate
    
    Set ThisCell = ActiveCell
    ColNameToSearch = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, WhatCol).Value2
    ActualNameToSearch = ActiveSheet.Cells(WhatRow, 1).Value2
    
    Set Builder = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ColNameToSearch)
    Set RangeToSearch = Builder.Columns(1)
    
    For i = 1 To Builder.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        log.WriteLine ("ActualName to Search:" + ActualNameToSearch + " C.Value2:" + " " + RangeToSearch.Cells(i, 2).Value2)
        If ActualNameToSearch = RangeToSearch.Cells(i, 2).Value2 Then
            X = 1
        End If
    Next i

    If X = 1 Then
        ActualNameToSearch = RangeToSearch.Cells(i, 2).Value2
        X = 0
    End If
 
Next Cell

End Function
```

Comment: Why not use indentation for your loops and if statements? Your code is hard to read. Also, it is better to use `Long` than `Integer` since you are risking overflow for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the Tips John :-)

Comment: It seems you think Resize parameters are rows values. They are not. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize

Comment: I was trying to use it as "from this point, expand selection by (TheseRows, TheseColumns).. 

Which part causes concern? - Am open to reccomendations, am relatively new at this

Comment: Maybe you want `Set StaffPageRange = StaffSht.Cells(StaffFirstRow, 1).Resize(StaffLastRow-StaffFirstRow,1)`?

Comment: So you mean "StaffLastRow" is a column number?

Comment: I guess it is!.. thats not at all confusing.. :-) - Looking at it, StaffLastRow just selects the whole of the B column

Comment: does not seems to be, given how it is calculated... `StaffLastRow = StaffSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is the last row with non empty first cell.

Comment: Did you consider to use for exaple sqlite as a database backend for that stuff and use simple sql querys ? There is a native connector for VBA out. I wont give me all that hussle by a text file and self created "querys". In Sqle ist very simple to query sort and whatever and get the result in a table or VBA Array. https://github.com/govert/SQLiteForExcel

Comment: Did you try to apply `BreakPoint`,`AddWatch` and `F8` key to go line by line to check problem, most of my problem solve with BreakPoint debugging.